# Bash convention for if ; then

Tags: bash, shell, coding-style

From this web page :

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html

It's mentioned the usage of the if bracket then convention which need a space after the semicolon :

> ;
>
> ```
> Command separator [semicolon]. Permits putting two or more commands on the same line.
>
> echo hello; echo there
>
>
> if [ -x "$filename" ]; then    #  Note the space after the semicolon.
> #+                   ^^
>   echo "File $filename exists."; cp $filename $filename.bak
> else   #                       ^^
>   echo "File $filename not found."; touch $filename
> fi; echo "File test complete."
>
> Note that the ";" sometimes needs to be escaped.
> ```

Does anyone know where is this coming from and if this is needed at all by certain shells?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has become the style in the last few years:

```
if [ -x "$filename" ]; then
   echo "hi"
fi
```

However, back when dinosaurs like Burroughs and Sperry Rand ruled the earth, I learned to write if statements like this:

```
if [ -x "$filename" ]
then
    echo "hi"
fi
```

Then, you don't even need a semicolon.

The new style with `then` on the same line as the `if` started in order to emulate the way `C` and other programming languages did their `if` statements:

```
if (! strcmp("foo", "bar")) {
   printf "Strings equal\n";
}
```

These programming languages put the opening curly brace on the same line as the `if`.

Comment: C does not require you to put the opening curly brace on the same line. its a coding convention and many people don't like this method [https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715/should-curly-braces-appear-on-their-own-line]

Answer (score 10):

Semicolon `;` is an *operator* (not a *keyword*, like braces `{ }`or a bang `!`) in Shell, so it doesn't need to be delimited with white space to be recognized in any POSIX-compliant shell.

However, doing so improves readability (for my taste).

Semicolon needs to be escaped if you mean a symbol "semicolon", not an operator.

Answer (score 1):

The space after the semicolon is not required by the syntax for any shell I know of, but it's good style and makes the code easier to read.

I suppose the "sometimes needs to be escaped" wording refers to cases like `echo foo\;bar`, where you don't want the semicolon to be interpreted as a separator by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that the space should be necessary there. There's nothing about requiring spaces in the [POSIX sh spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_03).

Empirically, the following works fine in both [bash](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/) 4.1.5(1) and [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell):

```
$ if true;then echo hi;else echo bye;fi
hi
$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never came across a shell that required a space in that context.
Just to make sure, I've asked on c.u.s., you can read the replies [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.shell/r6LvATxS_EU/Nv4anNsGIhgJ).