# How can I fix my Bash script?

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

Some code that I take from my script:

```
hh=$(bc -l <<< "scale=5; $h2-$h1")
delta=$(abs $hh)
echo "delta h = $delta"

for (( i=0; i <= ( ${#arr0[@]} - 1); i++ )); do
  if [ $delta > 0.03000000000000000000 ] && [ ${arr1[$i]} > 100 ] then 
    echo "attack Ddos"
    iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.162.1 -j DROP
        break
  else
    echo "No attack Ddos"
  fi
done
```

Its output:

```
delta h = .05526800237680984201
./trung1 (copy): line 115: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./trung1 (copy): line 115: `  else'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Your script seems to be complicated enough to be rewritten in `perl` or `python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are simply missing a semi-colon after your `if` statement :

```
hh=$(bc -l <<< "scale=5; $h2-$h1")
delta=$(abs $hh)
echo "delta h = $delta"

for (( i=0; i <= ( ${#arr0[@]} - 1); i++ )); do
  if [ $delta > 0.03000000000000000000 ] && [ ${arr1[$i]} > 100 ] ; then #There is either a semi-colon here, or a new line
    echo "attack Ddos"
    iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.162.1 -j DROP
        break
  else
    echo "No attack Ddos"
  fi
done
```

More reading : [Bash convention for if then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985327/bash-convention-for-if-then)

Answer (score 3):

You need a semicolon before `then`. `if-then` works the same as `for-do` in that respect.

Comment: Semicolon or line break.

Comment: Sure. Semicolon is the line break of lazy people such as myself.